# Production of React when using react-router-dom v6.4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, package.json, production

I made an application(myapp) that it is like `www.mysite.com/test/myapp/` format
I use Nginx and it looks like routing is OK
in package.json I use `HomePage:"/test/myapp/"` in order to reach the build correct links location relative to "/test/myapp/".

When I run the build for production purposes, I have no issue loading all assets from the server but it looks like the `react-router-dom ver 6.4` needs some adjustment too. Otherwise, it does not find the modules inside react. I tried to add `basename` as an attribute of `BrowserRouter` but still, it looks like nothing is working. I mean the resources are loaded (css,js,icon,...) but nothing shows when I go to [www.mysite.com/test/myapp/](http://www.mysite.com/test/myapp/) so I feel it is related to the "path" attribute in react-router-dom that does not understand when I am in root location as "/" which should not be considered as [www.mysite.com/](http://www.mysite.com/) rather should be considered as [www.mysite.com/test/myapp/](http://www.mysite.com/test/myapp/)

Does anyone have any advice?

In my entry app.js

```
  function App() {
      console.log("[APP]");
      return (
        <BrowserRouter basename="/test/myapp">
              <Routes>
                <Route
                  path="/"
                  element={
                    <Container maxWidth="sm">
                      <Module1/>
                    </Container>
                  }
                ></Route>
                <Route
                  path="/module2"
                  element={
                    <Container maxWidth="sm">
                      <Module2/>
                    </Container>
                  }
                ></Route>
              </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
```

Comment: What does "it does not find the modules inside react" mean? What do you mean by "nothing is  working"?

Comment: I mean the resources are loaded (css,js,icon,...) but nothing shows when I go to www.mysite.com/test/myapp/   so I feel it is related to the "path" attribute in react-router-dom that does not understand when I am in  root location as "/" which should not be considered as www.mysite.com/ rather should be considered as www.mysite.com/test/myapp/

Comment: Could you plz share your package.json code? It is difficult to provide correct info without checking code.

Comment: Where exactly is the app hosted? It is actually served up from that `"/test/myapp/"` directory? Is the server configured to redirect all app page requests to that app's root index.html file being served from `"/test/myapp/"`?

Answer (score 0):

In index.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>   
);
```

In App.js:

```
import {Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Module1/>} />
        <Route path="/module2" element={<Module2/>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hope it will be helpful.